# Pandas Dataframe: Get only the rows where a certain column value is maximum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
In [73]: data = {'ID':[1234,1234,1234,1234,1235,1235,1236,1237,1237,1237,1237], 'Date':['1/4/2001','1/4/2001','6/1/2003','6/1/2003', '7/1/1998', '7/1/1998', '4/23/2005', '7/1/2005','7/1/2005','7/1/2005','7/1/2005'], 'CalcYr': [2018, 2019, 2018, 2019, 2007, 2008, 2018, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019], 'Values':[0.1,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.6,0,0.1,0,0.2]}
In[74]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [75]: df
Out[75]: 
      ID       Date  CalcYr  Values
0   1234   1/4/2001    2018     0.1
1   1234   1/4/2001    2019     0.1
2   1234   6/1/2003    2018     0.2
3   1234   6/1/2003    2019     0.3
4   1235   7/1/1998    2007     0.3
5   1235   7/1/1998    2008     0.4
6   1236  4/23/2005    2018     0.6
7   1237   7/1/2005    2016     0.0
8   1237   7/1/2005    2017     0.1
9   1237   7/1/2005    2018     0.0
10  1237   7/1/2005    2019     0.2
```

What I would like to do is keep only one row for the same values of `ID` and `Date`, where the `CalcYr` is maximum. For example, for `ID` of 1234, and `Date` of 1/4/2001, I'd only keep the row where `CalcYr` is 2019. The result would be:

```
         ID       Date  CalcYr  Values
    0   1234   1/4/2001    2019     0.1
    1   1234   6/1/2003    2019     0.3
    2   1235   7/1/1998    2008     0.4
    3   1236  4/23/2005    2018     0.6
    4   1237   7/1/2005    2019     0.2
```

Comment: `df[df['CalcYr'].eq(df.groupby(['ID','Date'])['CalcYr'].transform('max'))]`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df.groupby(['ID','Date'], as_index=False).max()

     ID       Date  CalcYr  Values
0  1234   1/4/2001    2019     0.1
1  1234   6/1/2003    2019     0.3
2  1235   7/1/1998    2008     0.4
3  1236  4/23/2005    2018     0.6
4  1237   7/1/2005    2019     0.2
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work, but I am curious as to how it looks for the max value int he CalcYr column and not the Values column.